# In RoR, how do I get a subclass of my service class to recognize a class variable in its super class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, inheritance, service, abstract-class, class-variables

I’m using Rails 4.2.5.  I have this super class

```
class AbstractImportService

  def initialize(params)
    @init_url = params[:init_url]
  end

  private

    attr_reader :init_url
```

and then this class that inherits from it

```
class MyService < AbstractImportService

  def self.my_method(runner_id)
     puts "init_url: #{@init_url}"
     …
  end
```

The problem is, in the method “self.my_method,” the puts line prints out “init_url:” even if I initially the @init_url to something.  Rails doesn’t have a concept of protected so is there another way I can get sub-classes to recognize class member variables of the super class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@init_url = params[:init_url]`
is an instance variable, so you can't expect to get its value trying it to get it by
`self.my_method(runner_id)`
which is called on the MyService class (and not on an object of this class).
Try with:

```
class AbstractImportService

  def initialize(params)
    @init_url = params[:init_url]
  end

  private
  attr_reader :init_url

end

class MyService < AbstractImportService

  def my_instance_method
    "init_url: #{@init_url}"
  end
end

2.2.1 :004 > instance = MyService.new({init_url: "http://www.example.com"})
 => #<MyService:0x007fd5db892250 @init_url="http://www.example.com"> 
2.2.1 :005 > instance.my_instance_method
 => "init_url: http://www.example.com"
```

Comment: I'm not clear from your answer what hcanges I need to make so that I can recognize the value of "@init_url" within the MyService class.  Please elaborate and code samples are always useful.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit the answer above and add the code sample. Is it ok for you @Mike?